# unforgiving giant

Tags: meaning-in-context

> And if the coalition falls apart, as coalitions tend to do, the United States can be an **unforgiving giant**.
>
> > Source: The Next 100 Years by George Friedman

Is it a reference to some book?
The first line on google shows me that it may be some poem. But the link is empty and an author unknown.

Comment: It's certainly not a usage with any established currency, and I don't think it's intended to reference anything other than the fact that in economic terms the US *is* a "giant". Looking at [the full source text](https://wikileaks.org/gifiles/docs/27/274568_fw-the-next-100-years-by-george-friedman-abridgement-request.html) I see the word ***giant*** occurs no less than 7 times, which seems relatively unusual (none of the occurrences seem to be related to any *others* in the text). I'd say this writer just likes the word ***giant*** more than most other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In his book [*The Next 100 Years: A Forecast for the 21st Century*](https://books.google.com/books?id=r-g97KwH2GkC&pg=PA47&lpg=PA47&dq=And+if+the+coalition+falls+apart,+as+coalitions+tend+to+do,+the+United+States+can+be+an+unforgiving+giant.&source=bl&ots=dcakHqOxn5&sig=4e9L2QVDsU5x7dEtNb7OntMq9Jo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiek6fTzc3OAhUB5iYKHWjCCsMQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=And%20if%20the%20coalition%20falls%20apart%2C%20as%20coalitions%20tend%20to%20do%2C%20the%20United%20States%20can%20be%20an%20unforgiving%20giant.&f=false) , George Friedman talks about the context of smaller countries creating coalitions to stand up to larger countries.

The US is one of the "giants" in the world, along with Russia and China, and Friedman its that it is easier for smaller countries to ally themselves with the US rather than be part of an anti-US coalition.

If the coalition were to be part of an anti-US coalition and the coalition fell apart (as the author says they will over time), the US will have retribution or be an "unforgiving giant".